# problems with mp.start();

Tags: android, media-player

I have made some simple app like: touch button - get sound

It works on my phone, on emulators etc.

It looks like:

```
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.release();}

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, sound);
        mp.start();
```

however some people gets error "java.lang.NullPointerException" on line with mp.start();

how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 mp = new MediaPlayer();
 mp.setDataSource(path);
 mp.prepare();
 mp.start();
```

Hope this may help you

Answer (score 0):

`MediaPlayer.create()` might return null if creation failed (see [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20android.view.SurfaceHolder%29)). Add a nullpointer check after you have assigned mp.

Edit: You should insert:

```
if(mp != null){
    mp.start();
}
```

Comment: How it should look then? I'm begginer (sorry:)

Comment: I have added code for the null check. This will not crash, but it will also not play a sound. You may want to look more deeply into why your `MediaPlayer` isn't created.

Comment: thanks, it looks soo obvious. I use normal mp3 files hmm, in 99.99% it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**if your sound stay in res/raw folder then try this ::**

```
MediaPlayer mp_xmPlayer2 = new MediaPlayer();
                    mp_xmPlayer2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.error);
                    mp_xmPlayer2.start();
```

**if you like to play sound from any URI ::**

```
mPlayer.setDataSource(path);
                mPlayer.prepare();
                mPlayer.start();
```

**Make sure set permission in manifest:** `WriteExternalStorage`

Answer (score 0):

mp  should be initialized like this

```
MediaPlayer mp_xmPlayer2 = new MediaPlayer();
```